# Perturbation with positive diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have some matrix $A$ and I perturb it by some small amount: $A \to A + \delta A$. I am interested in determining the sign of the quantity $a^\dagger \delta A a$. Here is what I know:

- $a$ is an eigenvector of the unperturbed matrix $A$. Specifically, it is the eigenvector corresponding to the most negative eigenvalue of $A$.
- The diagonal elements of $\delta A$ are all positive.
- $A$ is Hermitian, and so is $\delta A$
- $A$ is an operator (it is infinite-dimensional)

Is it possible to determine the sign of the quantity of interest? Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the signs of the off-diagonal components, so I do not believe I can make any arguments about the positive-definiteness of $\delta A$. Thank you very much for the help! I am a physicist, so apologies in advance if this question is too vague or poorly-worded.

EDIT: to get $\delta A$, you suppose that $A$ is initially parameterized by some variable $q$. Then, you take the variation: $\delta A = \frac{\partial A}{\partial q} \delta q$

Comment: Typo! I will correct it in the main text

Comment: What is $\delta$? A number close to $1$? A matrix close to the identity?

Comment: For any fixed $x$, the map $A \mapsto x^\top A x$ is continuous. Assuming $A$ is not positive semi-definite, $a^\top A a$ would be negative, and so for a sufficiently small perturbation of $A$, we would also see $a^\top \delta A a$ be negative as well. How small is "sufficiently small"? It's impossible to know with the given information about $A$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is some (unknown) Hermitian matrix where all of the elements are small.

Comment: Ah, you had me confused with $A\to\delta A$, but I see now you've edited it to $A\to A+\delta A$, much better. But then is $a^{\dagger}\delta Aa$ supposed to be  $a^{\dagger}(A+\delta A)a$? Should some of the other statements about $\delta A$ be edited to be about $A+\delta A$?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the typo. I am still interested in the quantity $a^\dagger \delta A a$, as written